# dimension of input layer for embeddings in Keras

Tags: keras, embeddings

It is not clear to me whether there is any difference between specifying the input dimension
 `Input(shape=(20,))` or not  `Input(shape=(None,))` in the following example:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(None,)) 
emb = Embedding(86, 300) (input_layer) 
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(300)) (emb) 
output_layer = Dense(10, activation="softmax") (lstm)   
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)  
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])  
history = model.fit(my_x, my_y, epochs=1, batch_size=632, validation_split=0.1)
```

`my_x` (shape: 2000, 20) contains integers referring to characters, while `my_y` contains the one-hot encoding of some labels. With `Input(shape=(None,))`, I see that I could use `model.predict(my_x[:, 0:10])`, i.e., I could give only 10 characters as an input instead of 20: how is that possible? I was assuming that all the 20 dimensions in `my_x` were needed to predict the corresponding y.